# angular 2 input [type="file"] dimension

Tags: angular

there is the way to get height and width of image when you uploading it ?
When i upload and use function like this:

```
const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
console.log(fileList[0])
```

I only can find size there, no any width or height.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what you're doing in context but you may want to check this module. It will get the size of images. You can most likely install and use it.

https://github.com/image-size/image-size

https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size